# Multiple training variables in GradientTape tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following list of trainable_variables in tensorflow:

```
l_vars = [l_unary.trainable_variables, l_regularization.trainable_variables]
```

which is passed into the tape like so:

```
    grad_l_model = l_tape.gradient(tf.constant(l_loss), l_vars)
```

However, this gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'
```

when wrapping l_vars with tf.Variable, I get the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [5,5,3,32] != values[1].shape = [32] [Op:Pack] name: initial_value
```

```
tf.keras.layers.concatenate([l_unary.trainable_variables, l_regularization.trainable_variables], 0)
```

gives:

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs

How do I train multiple model variables with tensorflow together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your `l_vars` is not a list, but a list of lists, since each `trainable_variables` attribute is already a list in itself. You can simply use

```
l_vars = l_unary.trainable_variables + l_regularization.trainable_variables
```

to concatenate the two lists into one big list.